# Spaces in VM arguments RCPTT maven plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, eclipse-rcptt

Is there a way to specify a VM argument value that contains spaces using the rcptt maven plugin in the pom file?

Just putting the value straight forward the string is cut and only get the string C:\Program.

```
<vmArgs>
    <vmArg>-Dmyproperty=C:\Program Files\ABC</vmArg>
</vmArgs>
```

Also, I have tried enclosing the value in quotes but it did not work too.

```
<vmArgs>
    <vmArg>-Dmyproperty="C:\Program Files\ABC"</vmArg>
</vmArgs>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had you tried this?

```
<vmArgs>
    <vmArg>-Dmyproperty=C:\Program</vmArg>
    <vmArg>Files\ABC</vmArg>
</vmArgs>
```